# C# Reordering/Rendering Multiple Layers of Panels

Tags: c#, controls, layer

I am working on a fun project of trying to make a image editor,I would like to have the user able to create multiple layers of panels to do stuff on.
I have implemented the basic adding and removal of the layers successfully,but I am a bit unsure of the best way to set each panels "z height" and then render the layers in a particular order.

From what I have  found out online, I should use the `Controls.setchildindex` to set each panels z-order. All the panels are stored in a list so when I want to render the layers I can just iterate through the list.

I did look into using the `Windows.forms.control.canvas` but this seamed to complicate other parts of the program such as setting a 'custom' background colour.
Has anyone got any other ideas on layering multiple panels, is the way with using the `Controls.setchildindex` the best way forward?

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so after a little trial and error I got my layering system working.
It turns out it is easier than I though, simply removing all the canvas layers controls from the "container panel"(rootPanel) then re-adding them in the a particular order layers them panel according to that order.
I have included the method below which simply removes and re-adds the layers,I am using a `Dictionary<String,Panel> panelList`to store the panels,I hope someone finds my answer useful.

```
 private void reOrderLayers(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < rootPanel.Controls.Count; i++)
        {
            rootPanel.Controls.RemoveAt(i);
            rootPanel.Refresh();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < listBox.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            rootPanel.Controls.Add(panelList[listBox.Items[i].ToString()]);
            rootPanel.Refresh();
        }
    }
```